# Bootstrap: Content in the middle?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Is there a alternative way to write to have content in the middle and blank on both sides?

For example:

```
<div class="col-md-3"></div>

<div class="col-md-6"> 
  <div class="form-group">
     ....
  </div>
</div>  

<div class="col-md-3"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might take a look at [bootstrap offset](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting) property

Your code might look something like this:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3"> 
  <div class="form-group">
     ....
  </div>
</div>
```